# Is there a git config file to tell what to merge per branch

Tags: git

When merging a branch into current branch, I want to exclude only some files of that branch from merging or I want to include only some files specific to that branch from merging. I don't want to specify the files every time I merge a branch. A config file to track files per branch merge would be great, something like the one below.

**.git-branch-merge**

```
[development-branch]
include:
file2
file3
dir1/

[feature1-branch]
exclude:
file1
dir2
```

I wonder, am I using the `git` the wrong way to crave for this feature as I didn't find it yet?

Below is the directory structure of my repo currently I am working on. It has two branches, Master and Standalone.

```
+ MyRepo_Master
| + CommonDir1
| - CommonFile1
| - CommonFile2
| - PartlyCommonFile3(CMakelists.txt)
-------------------------------------
+ MyRepo_Standalone
| + CommonDir1
| - CommonFile1
| - CommonFile2
| - PartlyCommonFile3(CMakelists.txt)
| - ExclusiveFile1
| - ExclusiveFile2
| @ ExclusiveSubModule1
| @ ExclusiveSubModule2
```

I may work on either of the branches but pull a branch depending on the system I am working on. Let's say I am working on `Standalone` branch common and partly common files. I want these common files to be pushed to the `Master` branch and partly common files to be compared and edited before the push.

One can achieve this by maintaining the common files in the separate branch and make it's `.gitignore` to ignore the exclusive files of all the other branches. But merging the partly common files will be a mess.

Comment: Create different branch with different files and merge it

Comment: I don't get you. the other branch has the same file with different content which I don't want in the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

In git's design, the intent is that a commit is a snapshot of the entire project, and branches are alternate lines of evolution of the entire project.  Partial merges are not supported, are hard to do, and if you do them it may cause future operations to behave in unexpected ways.

That doesn't mean you *can't* do something different; but that's the model for which you're going to find good support in the tool.

Of course there's always a fine line between the case where a tool is unreasonably constraining you to work the way it wants you to work, and the case where you're trying to use a screwdriver as a hammer.  Because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, I can't say which is going on here.  Maybe git is the wrong tool for your job, or maybe there's fundamentally a better way to accomplish your end goal.

---

**Update:**  In fairness, the above doesn't entirely answer your question.  I suppose I should supply a way to do what you're asking.  With the reminder that I don't think this is a good idea and recommend that you instead reevaluate how your project interacts with git, you could do something like this:

You could create a data file in whatever format you find convenient to process, and then write a script.  The script would read `.git/MERGE_HEAD` to figure out what you're merging in (but beware that if you do an octopus merge there will be multiple entries; processing that case is considerably more difficult).  Then it would use the data in your file to decide if some files shouldn't be accepted, for each such file

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/the/file
```

Once all paths have been processed

```
git add .
```

There's not really an appropriate hook you can use to trigger this, so you'd then have to always use the `--no-commit` option when doing a `git merge`; then after resolving any legitimate conflicts (but before committing) you would run you script.  (You could have your script do the `commit` as its final step, I guess, but beware of accidentally committing unresolved conflicts.)

At the end of the day, what you get will generally be an "evil merge".  It hides changes relative to the natural result of merging its parents, and that can (a) confuse certain git commands, or (b) cause you to reason incorrectly about what certain git commands (like further merges between the affected branches) might do.

So I wouldn't do it; but if you really wanted to, you could.

Comment: writing a script is the first thing I got to mind but It could be easily implemented by git. can you suggest a better tool for this?

Comment: Even if it *could* be easily implemented by git (which I doubt), it runs against the grain of how git works.  That's 90% of the point I was trying to get across.  So I would expect them to deliberately *not* implement it.  As for tool recommendations, no, I don't have one.  If you want further advice, you can spell out what you're trying to accomplish; but my advice will probably be to accomplish it in a different way that's more in line with how git works.

Comment: I do agree that two branches diverge but there is always a common content between two branches, if not, why would they be part of the same repo? It's very efficient **not** to do the redundant modification on the common content.

Comment: What do you mean "do redundant modification on the common content"?  It sounds like you're making incorrect assumptions about how git structures its content.  If a file is unchanged then git leaves it alone.

Comment: I mean making same changes in multiple branches.

Comment: git attempts to detect "same change" conflicts and ignore them.  It does a pretty good job of it.  Still not clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you pull a branch to get these common changes, we get the non-common changes as well.

Comment: Sorry, but this is my last comment until you explain clearly in one place what you're trying to accomplish.  It's clear that your meaning isn't coming across in one-or-two-sentence comments, because this last comment appears to contradict what you said in the previous two.